# Filter slider item with Show/Hide using bxSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I have a bxslider on my webpage with the following options

```
$('#carousel').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 146,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 6,
    speed:500,
    adaptiveHeight: true,    
    moveSlides:3,
    infiniteLoop : false,
    hideControlOnEnd : true,    
    slideMargin: 10
});
```

Inside this slider I have multiple DOM element like the following

```
<div class="itemClass_XX_YY carouselItem">
  <div class="someClass"><img src="path/to/some/picture.png" /><span>SomeTitle</span></div>
</div>
```

In this code `class="item_XX_YY"` XX and YY are categories describing the picture.
For example let's say that the category animals is 1 (so XX=1) and the category Bears have for id 5 (YY=5). 
Every picture of bears inside my slider will have for class `item_1_5`

Basically what I want to do is to filter item's inside my bxSilder.
For now I'm using the following code

```
$('.categoryList').click(function() {
    var cat  = $(this).data('category');
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    $('.carouselItem').hide();
    $('.item_'+type+'_'+cat).show();
});
```

My filtering works fine but the bxSilder act quite wierdly with hidden element inside it.
The "next" and "prev" buttons seems to count any hidden element like if it wasn't hidden (which could be the expected behaviour).

However, I don't want my slider take account of hidden element. 
My question is, how can I filter my bxSlider's element on the fly without breaking the prev/next buttons?

---

**Edit** : Here is a fiddle describing the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/swrf991q/7/

Once you filter, the next & prev button doesn't work + the number of slides in the pager is still the same.

Comment: How is the element hidden? Using `display` or using `visibility`. Why are some elements hidden in the first place. Lastly give us a fiddle or a link where we can see this.

Comment: I'll add a JSFiddle Asap (probably tomorrow). For the hidden elements, i'm using jQuery `hide()` and `show()` functions which is a display none/block. However, I tried using visibility hidden/visible but the result is the same. The elements are hidden in the first place because i want to filter what's inside my slider. I have a lots of picture and for example just want to display bears or flowers (or rainbows...)

Comment: Unfortunatly, no. Every solution I tried lead to other bugs or wierd behaviours. I switched for another slider [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a long times, bxsilder doesn't allow you to filter items.
I used [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) instead.

If you really want to keep using the bxsilder, what you must do is quite complicated

- First of all, you need a hidden copy of all your element somewhere in your html.
- Start by destroying the slider with `destroySlider` function
- Then you should remove every element from the bxslider `$('#carousel').html('')`
- Now copy every element you want to see from the hidden copy to the slider div (you apply your filter here)
- Create a new slider.

I think that instead destroying the slider & creating it again, you could use the `redrawSlider` function but I've not tried it.